# Ordering posts in get_posts

Tags: get-posts

I am having a custom block which uses the following code to fetch a list of comma separated posts.

```
    $numberposts = "7,9,5,10";
    $post_ids = explode( ',', $numberposts );
    $args = array( 
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post__in' => $post_ids,
        'numberposts' => '9999999'
    );
    $list_posts = get_posts( $args );
```

The problem is that the returned data is not ordered by the original order of the ids supplied. Is it possible to do that? Can you please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the orderby to `post__in`. Here is a superior post loop:

```php
$args = [
    'post__in' => [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ],
    'orderby'  => 'post__in',
];

$q = new \WP_Query( $args );
if ( $q->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $q->have_posts() ) {
        $q->the_post();
        ?>
        <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
            <?php the_title(); ?>
        </article>
        <?php
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
} else {
    echo '<p>No posts found</p>';
}
```

Important changes:

- `get_posts` does not fire all the loop lifecycle filters, bypasses caches by default ( `suppress_filters` is set to true in `get_posts` ), and doesn't set the current post for you. It also uses `WP_Query` internally, so I cut out the middleman and used `WP_Query` directly. This loop is both faster, more expandable, and more compatible
- I removed `numberposts` and `post_type`, these are unnecessary and would actually slow down the query if WP used them. WP knows which posts you want via `post__in` so it'll just fetch those
- `orderby` is set to `post__in` so posts will appear in the same order they're requested
- I used a PHP array instead of using `explode` on a string ( which gives the same result so why do the extra work? )
- I used `the_ID` and `post_class` so the inner loops tags would have the appropriate classes

I ***strongly*** recommend you read through this document: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/ it will save a lot of time in the future and has a lot of examples.